# Dropdown menu did not work after I resize the page

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am using CSS to make drop-down menu. When I resized the page, the drop-down menu didn't work. It didn't do anything when I click on the menu. Also I would like to know that when I resize my page, the About menu from the nav bar does not show after resizing. I do not know how to fix the size when I resize the page.

This is my first time using CSS and HTML. I would love to learn from you guys here.

This is my HTML code

```
<head>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/pj2.css" rel="stylesheet" type"text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta charset= "UTF-8">
    <title>KeeNok</title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="wrap">

<!--Responsive menu-->
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Events 
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#">Past Events</a>
                  <a href="#">Future Events</a>
                </div>
              </div> 
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myfunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>

<!--Menu-->
    <div id="main_menu">
        <div class="logo_area">
            <a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\John\Documents\Other\Cooking\Kee Nok\graphics\KeeNokLogo.jpg" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="inner_main_menu">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Events</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Past Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Future Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--Popup Photos-->
    <div class="thumbs">
        <div id="Mian Kham" href="#"><img src="C:\Users\John\Documents\Other\Cooking\Kee Nok\Photos\1\Mian Kham.png" alt="Mian Kham"></div>
        <div id="Gai Tod" href="#"><img src="C:\Users\John\Documents\Other\Cooking\Kee Nok\Photos\1\Gai Tod.png" alt="Gai Tod"></div>
        <div id="Tom Khao Pod" href="#"><img src="C:\Users\John\Documents\Other\Cooking\Kee Nok\Photos\1\Tom Khao Pod.png" alt="Tom Khao Pod"></div>
    </div>  

<footer></footer>
</div> 
</body
```

This is my CSS code

```
body {
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.945);
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    overflow: auto;
    height:100%;


}

.wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 20px solid #9fd7fd;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.inner_main_menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1300px;

}

.inner_main_menu ul{
    margin: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 30px;
    z-index: 1;

}

.inner_main_menu ul li{
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

}

.inner_main_menu ul li:nth-child(1){
    float: left;
}



.inner_main_menu ul li a {
    color: #262626;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.inner_main_menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #eb3332;

}

.inner_main_menu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    margin: 0; 
}

.inner_main_menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

.inner_main_menu ul li ul li{
    float: left;

}

.inner_main_menu ul li ul li a{
    font-size: 15px;

}



#main_menu {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;

}

.logo_area img{
   max-width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    content: " ";
    margin-left: -150px;
    text-align: center;

}

#main_menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

.thumbs {   
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 80px 0;
}

.thumbs img{   
    max-width: 300px;

}


.topnav {
    background-color:#555d61;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
    float:left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;


} 

.active {

    color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px 16px;


}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#555d61;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;

}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #aaadad; 
    color: black;


} 
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color:  #aaadad; 
    color: black;

}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #aaadad; 
    color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display:block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
      display: none;
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }

  /* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive a.icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
```

[This is how my page look like before resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJyDI.jpg)

[This is my page looks like after resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DygIL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in your CSS that there's a comment which reads:

> *The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon*

I think you are missing the JavaScript you need to add the class to your navigation.

It will look something like this:

```
const icon = document.querySelector(".icon")
const nav = document.querySelector(".topnav")

icon.onclick = function() {
  nav.classList.toggle('responsive');
}
```